# Trying to find module folder to these syntaxerrors

Tags: javascript

```
at Object.configure (/home/bot/node_modules/log4js/lib/log4js.js:205:12)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bot/site.js:36:8)
at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
```

I'm trying to fix these syntax errors with my bad skill:D but there's a problem I can't find module.js anywhere. I'm trying to do betting website I think that's kinda big piece to chew but I think I will learn best with this way. I don't know why I'm telling you all this but yeah I already know HTML/CSS and javascript pretty well so I think I can handle this if I can just find those folders.

Comment: You should probably rather look at line 36 of `/home/bot/site.js`

Comment: Thanks man appreciate it!<3